# Application.Quit() doesn't quit the application

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

I have this simple piece of code in `C#` with `GTK#`:

`Main.cs`:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

namespace Apu{
    class MainClass{
        public static void Main(string[] args){
            Application.Init();
            new ShowForm();
            Application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

`ShowForm.cs`

```
public partial class ShowForm: Gtk.Window{  
    public ShowForm(): base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel){
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(
            this, 
            DialogFlags.DestroyWithParent, 
            MessageType.Error,
            ButtonsType.None,
            "Test"
        );

        md.SetPosition(Gtk.WindowPosition.CenterAlways);
        md.Title = "Test window";
        md.AddButton("Don't stop", ResponseType.Ok);
        md.AddButton("Stop", ResponseType.Cancel);

        ResponseType result = (ResponseType)md.Run();

        if (result.Equals(ResponseType.Cancel)) {
            Console.WriteLine("Quit!");
            md.DestroyEvent += delegate {
                Application.Quit();
            };
            /*md.DeleteEvent += delegate {
                Application.Quit();
            };*/
        }

        md.Destroy();
    }
}
```

Console outputs `Quit!`, but the program doesn't quit. Neither `DestroyEvent` nor `DeleteEvent` works. Can anyone explain why? This is my first app in `c#`, my first time using `gtk#`. I use monodevelop as my IDE.

**EDIT**

`Application.Exit()` gives error: `Gtk.Application does not contain a definition for 'Exit'`.

Comment: it gives an error, see my edited question.

Comment: why don't you just call Application.Quit() instead of adding it to the event md.DestroyEvent?  You don't have to destroy the message dialog, since the garbage collection will do that for you.

Comment: @NickBray good suggestion, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried debugging using some breakpoints in that if statement? Are you sure the application enters in the if block?

Comment: according to this link http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp:_Hello_World Application.Quit(); should work.. notice how they are using the Delegate Event as well

Comment: @AlbertoSolano: I was sure, `Console.WriteLine` did output `Quit!`; @DJKRAZE: thanks for the link, I saw it too and was so surprised that it didn't work that I had to post here ; )

Comment: Use Application.Run(new ShowForm()) instead.  Now your app terminates when the window is closed.

Comment: Has Passant suggestion should also work as an answer I am curious to know if maialithar would try that code suggestion

Comment: @DJKRAZE I will try it later today

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to close the process, try Environment.Exit(0)

Comment: @DJKRAZE: sorry, I must have misunderstood your answer

Comment: Environment.Exit() is a rude abort, non of the normal cleanup happens.  This tends to byte sooner or later.  Usually later and very hard to diagnose.

Comment: I also wonder if there is a Method conflict / collision going on because winforms uses Application and gtk uses Application I would Alias the gtk Assembly and call it's Alias.Application.Quit(); for example using _gtk = Gtk;

Comment: @DJKRAZE I will try it later today

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
md.Destroyed += delegate {
    Application.Quit();
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help.